# How to set methods private to module?

Tags: d, private-members

I have two D classes in one module. I would like class A to have a property, which can only be accessed from class A and class B. How would I do this?

```
class A {
    int a = 5; // Make this accessible to, and only to, B. 
}

class B {
    this(in A pA) {
        int b = pA.a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`private` is private to a module, not a class. So, marking a symbol as `private` makes it so that only stuff in that module can access it.

`package` makes it so that only stuff in the same package can access the symbol.

`protected` makes it so that only stuff in that class and in classes derived from that class can access the symbol (unlike the others, `protected` makes no sense outside of classes).

`public` makes it so that anything can access the symbol.

`private` and `package` functions are never virtual, whereas `protected` and `public` functions are always virtual unless the compiler is able to determine that they don't need to be (which at this point, can pretty much only happen when the function is `final` and doesn't override a function in a base class).

So, as long as your two classes are in the same module, and their members are private, they can access each others members - as can anything else within the module - but nothing outside the module can access them. There is no way to restrict access within a module except for when the symbol is local to a function, so if you want to make it so that one class cannot access the members of another, then you're going to need to put them in separate modules.

Answer (score 4):

just add `private`

the access modifiers are module based with `protected` as the only exception

http://dlang.org/attribute.html#ProtectionAttribute (emph mine)

> Private means that only members of the enclosing class can access the member, **or members and functions in the same module as the enclosing class.** Private members cannot be overridden. Private module members are equivalent to static declarations in C programs.